# Executing Vim commands from a shell script

Tags: bash, vim

I am writing a Bash script that should open `ls` man page then expand the page.

what I did:
bash$ `vim +Man\ ls -c Wo`
What I exbect to happen that the bash open ls manpage then execute keybind `<C-w>o` to expand
this part `-c Wo` is wrong

Is there a practical way to execute Vim commands from the shell script?

Comment: This opens man page, not like `:Man` because `:Man` has colored, and `man ls | vim -` not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-c` and `+` expect a command-line mode command (AKA "Ex command", the commands that start with `:`) but `<C-w>o` is a normal mode command so it can't be used directly, here.

One way to get around this problem would be to use `:help :normal` and your shell's ability to insert control characters via `<C-v>`:

```
$ vim +Man\ ls +normal\ ^Wo
```

with `^W` being a literal `<C-w>` character obtained by pressing `<C-v>` followed by `<C-w>`.

But using the command-line mode equivalent of `<C-w>o` seems like a better idea:

```
$ vim +Man\ ls +wincmd\ o
```

See `:help :wincmd`.

Comment: The second solution `wincmd` work fine, but the first not work with me, also I tried `C-v` follow by `, buts me in V-block mode, so this not work as we expected here. Thanks alot.

Comment: You need to be in insert mode for that.

Comment: I ran second command, it gave `E492: Not an editor command: Man ls`

Comment: @Philippe, `:Man` has to be enabled manually, which OP already did. See `:help :Man`.